# formula or tips for arranging multiple column into one column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to combine or arrange multiple column into one column
 for example:

```
location1  qty      location2      qty
abbb        1       ccss            1
csss        1       ccss            1
abbb        1       abbb            1
assd        1       assd            1
csss        1       ccss            1
```

and result is:

```
location1   qty
abbb         2
csss         2
assd         1
location2   qty
ccss         3
abbb         1
assd         1
```

like this:

[image]

Comment: use power query.

Comment: ^^set up as two tables and append one to the other

Comment: How have you tried to accomplish what you want?  What problems have you run into that we can help you with?

Comment: Thank your very much sir
I got the result that I wanted.
because i have to consolidate multiple data with multiple columns and combine it into 1 columns,
so i just trying different way to make it faster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **Power Query**. It is an add-in for Excel 2010+ (by default in 2016 known as Get & Transform). There you can connect directly your sources of data and you will have a lot of tools to transform your data.

For your case in specific try this steps:

[image]

To unpivot and Group by count:

[image]

Comment: Thanks sir it is very helpful to me

Comment: Hey I saw the update in your question. Check my answer again to give you an idea for your problem :)

Comment: Hi Virtualdvid!
your so amazing!
you have given a quick way to consolidate
Thank you very much sir ^^
this is very useful when consolidating a data in warehouse inventory